# Re-sizing circle SVG in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to change the size of dots on a map in D3.  Basically, just want to re-size the circle SVG in D3.  I just want all the circles to be smaller, not trying to create proportional symbols.  Here's my circles:

```
var centroid = map.selectAll(".centroid")
    .data(centroid.features)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d",path)
    .attr("r", 100)
    .attr("class", function(d){
        return "centroid "+d.properties.info_city;

    })
```

It's not working. I know that I can't do this in CSS, any thoughts on how to accomplish this in javascript as I'm trying to do?  Thanks all!

[image]

Comment: When do you want to resize them? Doesn't changing the "r" value work?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this plunker and let's move on from there: http://plnkr.co/edit/lKtCBKFS764MThajrqxX?p=preview

This map has similar centroids like yours. These are defined in:

```
 g.selectAll(".centroid").data(centroids)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "centroid")
      .attr("fill", fill)
      .attr("stroke", stroke)
      .attr("stroke-width", strokeWidth)
      .attr("r", radius)
      .attr("cx", function (d){ return d[0]; })
      .attr("cy", function (d){ return d[1]; });
```

By changing `.attr("r", radius)` line (which is 6 in the config) to `.attr("r", 2)` you will get smaller circles

Here's the changed one: http://plnkr.co/edit/JUpMlnhZvZNacAIzI502?p=preview

I think you are trying to change the wrong part of the code since you should change the "r" of the circle elements not the "path" element ( I don't think path element even has a "r" attribute).

If your circles are drawn by a path then you must change the algorithm that draws those circles.

Comment: Thanks Echonax, my circles are drawn by a path, but not sure really how to proceed.  I've looked at the code but mine is different because I'm drawing with a path, I beleive.

Comment: @Echonax, it's actually possible to draw a circle using `path`. This is a feature of TopoJSONs when the collection's type is "point" or "multipoint".

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Yes of course. I just didn't know that there was an implementation in d3 to do that :) thats why I added my final line in the answer. And I was going to delete my answer in a bit since yours is more relevant :)

Comment: Don't delete your answer, leave it here, so a future user can see how to use circles instead of paths.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the centroid coordinates to append a `path` as if it was a circle. This is not usual, the most common choice would be using a SVG `circle`, but it's OK... actually, Bostock does the same [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4408297).

The only problem is, as these are `paths`, not `circles`, changing the radius (`r`) will have no effect. So, to change the size of these "circles", this is what you have to do: find your `d3.geo.path` and add `pointRadius` to it.

```
var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection)
    .pointRadius(someValue);
```

Where `someValue` is, of course, some numeric value that fits your needs.

PS: for this to work properly, the `types` in your TopoJSON have to be `"Point"` or `"MultiPoint"`.

Comment: You rule!  Thanks a bunch.  That worked!  Now, I assume for styling (transparency, fill, stroke, etc) I'd go to CSS for that is best practice?